# gtk+2.0のコンパイルができません。

Tags: windows, c, gtk

gtk+2.0のコンパイルができません。
OS：Windows
コンパイラ：GCC
ソースファイル：J:\gtk\main.c
gtk+-bundle_3.10.4-20131202_win32.zipをJ:\gtk\gtkに展開しました。

バッチファイルで

```
set PATH=gtk\bin\;%PATH%
cmd
```

を実行し、コマンドプロンプトで

```
gcc -o hbf.exe main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
```

を実行したところ

```
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-2.0: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
```

とエラーが出ました。

コンパイルするためには、どうしたらいいですか。

Comment: コンパイルできない原因については既に他の方から回答があるのでそちらを参照していただくとして、ファイル名「gtk+-bundle_3.10.4(略)」から推測するに、コンパイルしようとしているのはgtk+のバージョン2.0ではなくて3.0系ではないですか？そしてbundleのパッケージには既にコンパイル済みの実行ファイルが同梱されていませんか？[ここにあるファイル](http://win32builder.gnome.org/) ですよね？

Answer (score 1):

Windows のコマンドプロンプトはバッククォートに対応していません。
msys もしくは msys2 を使ってそのシェル上から実行するか、Makefile にコマンドを書いて `mingw32-make` を実行して下さい。

**追記**

ちなみに...

> gcc -o hbf.exe main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0

終わりのバッククォートが抜けていますよ。

Answer (score 1):

FORコマンドを使えばcmd.exeでもできなくはなさそうですが、回りくどいので素直にbash.exeなどUNIX系のシェルを使った方が良いかもしれません。

```
FOR /F ["オプション"] %変数 IN ('コマンド') DO コマンド [コマンド パラメーター]
    または usebackq オプションの場合:
FOR /F ["オプション"] %変数 IN (`コマンド`) DO コマンド [コマンド パラメーター]
```

例.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0') DO @gcc -o hbf.exe main.c %i
```